# Complex number containing vectors in R

Tags: r

I am trying to make a Mandelbrot set code in R from scratch without using any predefined functions. But I am getting an error message saying-

> In complex(real = rl, imaginary = hig) :
> imaginary parts discarded in coercion

I think that means complex numbers can't be stored in vectors.

Please tell me whether I am right or wrong and also please help me to solve this error.

Below is my code.

```
listx=c()
z=0
inmbs=F
imgdispl=matrix(c(),441 ,441 )
for (hig in seq(-220,220,1)){
  for (wid in seq(-220,220,1)){
    listx=c()
    z=0
    for (k in 0:5){
      inmbs=F
      xx=z^2
      rl=xx+wid
      l = complex(real = rl, imaginary = hig)
      if (l %in% listx){
        inmbs=T
        break
      }
      else{
        append(listx,l)
        z=l
      }
    }
    if (inmbs==T){
      imgdispl[hig+221,wid+221]=1
    }
    else{
      imgdispl[hig+221,wid+221]=0  
    }
  }
}
image(imgdispl)
```

updated code:

```
listx=c()
z=0
inmbs=F
imgdispl=matrix(c(0),441 ,441 )
for (hig in seq(-220,220,1)){
  for (wid in seq(-220,220,1)){
    listx=c()
    z=0
    for (k in 0:5){
      inmbs=F
      xx=z^2
      coor = complex(real = wid/15, imaginary = hig/15)
      l=xx+coor
      if (l %in% listx){
        inmbs=T
        break
      }
      else{
        append(listx,l)
        z=l
      }
    }
    if (inmbs==T){
      imgdispl[hig+221,wid+221]=1
    }
    else{
      imgdispl[hig+221,wid+221]=0  
    }
  }
}
image(imgdispl)
```

Comment: ok, thank you. I will try to resolve that error in my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you debug your code you'll see that `rl` becomes complex.
The message tells you that only the real part is used in the call to:

```
l = complex(real = rl, imaginary = hig)
```

If you follow these [instructions](https://www.math.univ-toulouse.fr/%7Echeritat/wiki-draw/index.php/Mandelbrot_set), you get:

```
z=0
N=10
inmbs=F
imgdispl=matrix(c(0),441 ,441 )
for (hig in seq(-220,220,1)){
  for (wid in seq(-220,220,1)){
    coor = complex(real = wid/220, imaginary = hig/220)
    z=0
    
    for (k in 0:N){
      inmbs=F
      if ((Re(z)^2+Im(z)^2)>4){
        inmbs=T
        break
      }
    z = z^2 + coor
    }
    if (inmbs==T){
      imgdispl[hig+221,wid+221]=1
    }
    else{
      imgdispl[hig+221,wid+221]=0  
    }
  }
}
image(imgdispl)
```

[image]

Comment: I have changed that to adding the coordinates to the z^2 after the coordinates are found. But now it's giving me a blank chart. I am updating my post to include my updated code. I even tried dividing it by 15 to give it a zoom in.

Comment: `listx` is always equal to NULL because you should write :`listx <- append(listx,l)`

Comment: I'm afraid I'm still getting a matrix filled with zeroes. Is there something wrong with the initial data I gave to the matrix?

Comment: Not quite, after the above correction, `max(imgdisp)` gives me 1, and I see 4 red pixels in the middle of the image. You should perhaps review more in detail the algorithm you're using.

Comment: hmm. I have solved my error and also seen your algorithm. Yours is definitely way faster because even with a 100 iterations, mine is giving a very bad image.